# How to get the unused attributes from the table Magento 2 using SQL Query

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, attributes, eav-attributes

I need to get the unused attributes from Magento DB that is not assigned to the Attribute set and not assigned to the production. Also i need to get the unused attribute sets. from Magento table

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer had used this Query but i think it is not giving correct answer
SELECT attribute_id, attribute_code, frontend_label
FROM eav_attribute
WHERE entity_type_id = 4
AND attribute_id NOT IN(SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_entity_attribute);